# Use `value` key and use in conditional `classname` React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to use the value of key `value` in the `className` for rendering conditional className
something like

```
<li value=value={this.checkValue()} className={value ? 'enable' : 'disable'}> </li>

checkValue = () => {
// My function returns true or false on some condition
        if (!isEmpty(threat_groups)) {
            return true;
        }
        
    }
```

Is it possible to do something like this?
The best way to do this doesn't want to use the state as these are 100 of `<li>`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Empty `<li>`'s rendered disabled or no empty `<li>`'s rendered at all?

Comment: This doesn't take any parameter. So, it's the same value for all `li`? Put it in a variable and use it? Also, `li`s don't have `value` attribute

Comment: Does your className depends on the checkValue() function ?

Comment: @SijuSamson Yes my className class that it will be enabled or disabled it depends on what checkValue() returns.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov that if it's enabled then, Different css will apply and onClick will work otherwise in case of disabled different css and onclick will not work.

Comment: @adiga I didn't get you. Can you please give some reference. How to do?
One more thing all <li> will have different values

Answer (score 0):

```
<li value={() => this.checkValue(value)} className={checkValue() ? 'enable' : 'disable'}> </li>
```

Now if checkValue() returns true class enable will be activated.

```
checkValue = (parameter) => {
  if (parameter) {
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: You can try to add a key in your object (assuming it to be an object), and you can change the value in the function checkValue(), and then add class depending upon that key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the useRef hook and do something like if you don't want to calculate it twice / you can just save the answer to a variable and pass it

```
const listItemRef = useRef(null);

<li ref={listItemRef} value={this.checkValue()} className={listItemRef.current?.value ? 'enable' : 'disable'}> </li>

checkValue = () => {
// My function returns true or false on some condition
        if (!isEmpty(threat_groups)) {
            return true;
        }
        
    }
```

OR

```
checkValue = () => {
// My function returns true or false on some condition
        if (!isEmpty(threat_groups)) {
            return true;
        }
        
    }
const value = checkValue();

<li value={value} className={value ? 'enable' : 'disable'}> </li>
```